# Case statement for join condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi I want to use case statement in where condition or some similar logic.
I want to ignore where condition when there are no rows in tmp_collaboration table and use the condition when table has some rows in it.

```
Select clbid from tmp_collaboration;

select customer_id, product_id ,clbid 
from customers c
    where hdr_id = 10
          and clbid in (select clbid from tmp_collaboration)
          and status = 'y';
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select customer_id, product_id ,clbid 
from customers c
where hdr_id = 10 and status = 'y' and
      (clbid in (select clbid from tmp_collaboration) or
       not exists (select 1 from tmp_collaboration)
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use a JOIN  .. if there are rows in table the rows  are involved  otherwise not  .

```
select customer_id, product_id ,clbid 
from customers c
INNER JOIN tmp_collaboration t on t.clbid = c.clbid
    AND  hdr_id = 10
    AND status = 'y';
```